# jQuery ui autocomplete combobox dropdown position

Tags: jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, combobox, position

I am using jQuery ui autocomplete combobox in my project. This widget or plugin is placed at 'Sticky Footer' of the page. This is working fine. Since autocomplete combobox is on footer strip so when autocomplete dropdown menu is open, it goes out of page.

Please see this screenshot http://prntscr.com/mpa11

I want this dropdown menu should appear on top of input field instead of bottom of input field.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well no one replied but i have solved this problem. I just added the position property in the source file of combobox and its solved this problem.

```
                    position: {
                        my: "left top",
                        at: "left bottom",
                        collision: "fit flip"
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, this helped me.
Just to make it a bit clearer, position is a parameter to autocomplete:

```
this.input = $( "<input>" )
    .insertAfter( this.element )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input" )
      .autocomplete({
          position:{
            collision:"fit flip"  
          },
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
          select:function(event,ui){
            this.value = ui.item.value;
            if(that.options.script){
                        that.options.script();
                    }
            $(this).blur();
          },search:function(event,ui){
            if(event.originalEvent){
                            if(that.options.script){
                            that.options.script();
                        }
                    }
                      },
        source: this.options.source?this.options.source:[]
      }).focus(function(){
          $(this).autocomplete( "search", "" );
      })
      .tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
      });
```